# Validating that a comma-separated list of values follows a specific sequence

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have a loop I created to check if the values entered match an ordering, depending on the augment passed. So for example the ordering constraint must be

```
"SU", "M", "TU", "W", "TH", "F", "SA"
```

therefore if the user enters the following inputs

`"SU,M,TU,SA"` this is correct

however if the user enters

`"SU,TH,M"` this is incorrect since `M` should come before `TH`

The coding has been implemented and works fine however i don't find this was the best way of coding it, can anyone help me code it more efficiently?

```
  Function validExDays(exDays As String)
    Dim found As Boolean
    found = False

    If Len(exDays) >= 1 And Not IsNull(exDays) Then

    Dim NumOfCommas As Integer
    NumOfCommas = InstrCount(exDays, ",")

    Dim days(0 To 7) As String
    days(0) = ","
    days(1) = "SU"
    days(2) = "M"
    days(3) = "TU"
    days(4) = "W"
    days(5) = "TH"
    days(6) = "F"
    days(7) = "SA"
    Dim i, j, k, l, m, o, p, q As Integer
    i = 1
    j = 1
    k = 1
    l = 1
    m = 1
    o = 1
    p = 1
    q = 1


        Do While i <= 7
            If NumOfCommas = 0 Then
                'One day input check
                If i = 1 Then
                     Do While j <= 7
                        If UCase(exDays) = days(j) Then
                            found = True
                            Exit Do
                        End If
                        j = j + 1
                     Loop
                End If
            End If

            'Two day input check
            j = 1
            If NumOfCommas = 1 Then
                If found = False And i = 2 Then
                    Do While j <= 7
                        Do While k <= 7
                           If UCase(exDays) = days(j) + days(0) + days(k) Then
                               found = True
                               Exit Do
                           End If
                           k = k + 1
                        Loop

                        If found = False Then
                           j = j + 1
                           k = j
                        Else
                            Exit Do
                        End If
                    Loop
                End If
            End If

            'Three day input check
```

So the string value entered can be "SU,M,F" or "SU,F" or any other combination but whatever items are included must be in the correct order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is a bit more compact. It uses the `Split()` function to break out the components, and uses a `Dictionary` object to hold the index values of each valid component

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function IsValidExDays(exDays As String) As Boolean
    Dim rtn As Boolean
    Dim valueArray() As String, valueItem As Variant
    Dim maxValue As Integer
    Dim dict As Object  ' Scripting.Dictionary

    rtn = True

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.Add "SU", 1
    dict.Add "M", 2
    dict.Add "TU", 3
    dict.Add "W", 4
    dict.Add "TH", 5
    dict.Add "F", 6
    dict.Add "SA", 7

    maxValue = 0
    valueArray = Split(exDays, ",")
    For Each valueItem In valueArray
        If dict.Exists(valueItem) Then
            If dict(valueItem) > maxValue Then
                maxValue = dict(valueItem)
            Else
                rtn = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Else
            rtn = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    Set dict = Nothing
    IsValidExDays = rtn
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in Access, why don't you make an entry form with checkboxes that will always return the parameters in the order you expect?